# How do I scroll through EEG data using the MNE package?

Tags: python, plot, mne-python

I'm learning the basics of the MNE package for EEG analysis. I'm able to load my data (.edf format) and perform various operations. However, a plot feature described at

https://mne.tools/stable/auto_tutorials/raw/plot_40_visualize_raw.html#interactive-data-browsing-with-raw-plot

indicates I should be able to scroll through the data.

Here's my code:

```
 import mne as mn
 raw = mn.io.read_raw_edf("patient_019.edf",preload=True)
 raw.plot();
```

The data is a 10-minute recording from 46 channels and the result shows the default 20 channels and first 10 seconds. There is a HELP button in the lower-left corner of the window, but's inactive.

I've tried the keyboard shortcuts at the above help URL, but none of them work. Is there an additional package I need in order to scroll through the graphs? I'm doing this in a Jupyter notebook, Python 3, Mac OS Catalina.

[image: EEG graph imported using MNE]

Comment: Does anyone know how to remove the 'Help' button from appearing when plotting in 'inline' mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this before plotting does the trick:

```
%matplotlib qt
```